# Oracle - 'Expression is of wrong type' Return table of record type in package

Tags: oracle, function, types, package

I'm getting 'expression is of wrong type' when trying to test a function defined in a package that returns a table of record type.
Here's the header:

```
create or replace package pck_prestamos is
type r_cuotas is record
    (saldo_capital number(12),
    amortizacion number(12),
    interes number(12),
    seguro_vida number(8),
    monto_cuota number(15),
    fecha_vencimiento date);
type t_cuotas is table of r_cuotas
    index by binary_integer;
--v_cuotas t_cuotas;
function f_calcular_cuotas(monto_p number,t_i_a number, plazo_p number, fecha_d date) return t_cuotas;
end;
/
```

And here's the body:

```
create or replace package body pck_prestamos is
function f_calcular_cuotas(monto_p number,t_i_a number, plazo_p number, fecha_d date) return t_cuotas is
    saldo_capital_ant number;
    amortizacion_capital_ant number;
    diferencia number;
    porc_seg_v gen_parametros.porc_seg_vida%type;
    v_cuotasf t_cuotas;
begin
    select porc_seg_vida into porc_seg_v
        from gen_parametros;
    for i in 1..plazo_p loop
        if i = 1 then 
            v_cuotasf(i).saldo_capital := monto_p;
            saldo_capital_ant := v_cuotasf(i).saldo_capital;
            amortizacion_capital_ant := monto_p/plazo_p;
        else
            v_cuotasf(i).saldo_capital := saldo_capital_ant - amortizacion_capital_ant;
            saldo_capital_ant := v_cuotasf(i).saldo_capital;
        end if;
        if i = plazo_p then
            diferencia := v_cuotasf(i).saldo_capital - amortizacion_capital_ant;
            v_cuotasf(i).amortizacion := (monto_p/plazo_p) + diferencia;
        else 
            v_cuotasf(i).amortizacion := monto_p/plazo_p;
        end if;
        v_cuotasf(i).interes := ((t_i_a/12)/100)*v_cuotasf(i).saldo_capital;
        v_cuotasf(i).seguro_vida := (porc_seg_v/100)*v_cuotasf(i).saldo_capital;
        v_cuotasf(i).monto_cuota := v_cuotasf(i).amortizacion + v_cuotasf(i).interes + v_cuotasf(i).seguro_vida;
        v_cuotasf(i).fecha_vencimiento := fecha_d + 30*i; 
    end loop;
    return v_cuotasf;
end;
end;
/
```

Here's how I'm trying to test it:

```
declare
type r_cuotas is record
    (saldo_capital number(12),
    amortizacion number(12),
    interes number(12),
    seguro_vida number(8),
    monto_cuota number(15),
    fecha_vencimiento date);
type t_cuotas is table of r_cuotas
    index by binary_integer;
v_cuotas t_cuotas;
begin
v_cuotas := pck_prestamos.f_calcular_cuotas(10000000,10,18,sysdate);
end;
/
```

Both parts of the package compile without problems.
The full error is:

```
ERROR at line 13:  
ORA-06550: line 13, column 13:  
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type  
ORA-06550: line 13, column 1:  
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the point of view of Oracle the `t_cuotas` declared in your test block is a different type from the one declared in your package, even though they may have the same elements and "look" the same to you and me. You need to use the `t_cuotas` defined in your package by qualifying it with the package name:

```
declare
  v_cuotas pck_prestamos.t_cuotas;
begin
  v_cuotas := pck_prestamos.f_calcular_cuotas(10000000,10,18,sysdate);
end;
/
```

Give that a try.